Backend says isAuthenticated is true/ frontend says isAuthenticated is false
Im using passport js google oauth20. Upon fetching from the backend and console.logging the data I get false. I'm not sure what's causing this
Frontend
 const [isauthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000'
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuthStatus = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/auth/status`);
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setIsAuthenticated(data.isAuthenticated); // Update state based on 'loggedIn' flag
          console.log(data.isAuthenticated)
        } else {
          console.error('Error checking authentication status:', response.statusText);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error checking authentication status:', error);
      }
    };

    checkAuthStatus();
  }, []);

Backend
router.get('/status', (req, res) => {
    // Check if user is authenticated
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      // If authenticated, send status 200 and isAuthenticated as true
      res.status(200).json({ isAuthenticated: true });
    } else {
      // If not authenticated, send status 200 and isAuthenticated as false
      res.status(401).json({ isAuthenticated: false });
    }
  });

